# JMeter testing date - generate and send date - send by http protocol and receive by websocket

Tags: java, http, websocket, jmeter

I testing application back end in JMeter.
This application streaming event for live.
I would like do in JMeter so that date will send by http and receive by websocket.
and i would like doing in JMeter date generator, so that the date return specific event. and i would like check in jmeter, if user send all date,

what i will the best do it in Jmeter? what is the best way to do it in Jmeter?
please, descirbe me this step by step

Answer (score 2):

There are following functions which you can find useful:

- [__randomDate()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomDate) - produces a random date in a given range in a given format
- [__timeShift()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) - produces current timestamp with a given amount of time unit (days, hours, seconds) added or subtracted
- [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) - returns current timestamp in a given format
- [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) - when above functions are not enough

Check out [Creating Dates in JMeter Using the TimeShift Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function) article for more information and some examples.

Once you generate and send the required date to your server you can validate the outcome using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion).